# How to prevent accidental launch of Camera app from lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have an Archos Helium 50 phone running Android 4.3. It often activates the Camera app while the phone is still in my pocket. Plus, since it's dark inside my pocket, it activates the flash — this drains *a lot* of battery.

I tried to disable it but I didn't find any option in the menus which would allow me to do so. What can I try?  Did I miss some hidden menu?

Please note that the phone is not rooted; I absolutely refuse to root it.

Comment: You mean that when it captures the image it triggers the flash since it loads the "dark scene"  or you mean it triggers the flash even without triggering the camera?

Comment: I don't really know in fact @FiN . What I would like to do is disable camera on lock screen

Comment: Your Question is not clear, the camera get activated when you are making it unlock or what? @Thomas

Comment: Do you have any security or swipe enabled?

Comment: @Sridhar when I walk on the street, I sometimes have my hand in my pocket which, sometimes activate the camera from the lockscreen. Then the camera stays activated for a while which drain my battery. I want to know if there is a way to forbid the camera from the lockscreen? - Fin: Pin security is enabled

Comment: It's odd that your OS activates the flashlight  without unlocking the phone using PIN. Anyhow, have you tried any third-party lockscreen app? They would replace your stock lockscreen with option to add or remove Camera widget from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Lock Screen Policy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.chislonchow.deviceadminkeyguard) App and disable the Camera.

[image: Lock Screen Policy]

**Disable multiple 3rd party widgets on the lockscreen. Also removes lockscreen camera access on some devices**

*WARNING: 
Not intended for use on Android 5.x*

Comment: Is there some tool for the same on Android L versions?

Comment: Please avoid making superfluous edits even though the post is yours. Revision 5 and 6 are completely superfluous and shouldn't have been made.

Answer (score 0):

[Lockscreen Policy (<= KitKat)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.chislonchow.deviceadminkeyguard&referrer=utm_source%3D42matters.com%26utm_medium%3DWidgetWeb) is a third-party software which disables widgets on lock screen. You can give it a shot.